# Threads in Azure Cloud Service Worker Role not responding after Task.Delay

Tags: async-await, task-parallel-library, workflow-foundation-4, azure-worker-roles, azure-cloud-services

We have our application hosted on Azure Cloud Service containing a Web Role and a Worker Role. The worker role is used for running workflows using Windows Workflow Foundation and other processing works.

We are facing an issue where on encountering a Task.Delay, the thread stops responding in the Worker Role. Initially we were using the Task.Delay in a Custom Code Activity inside Workflow Foundation and on encountering the Task.Delay, the subsequent activities in the workflow would never get triggered. We tried to modify the logic by using a delay activity but faced the same issue.
Recently we changed the logic where are executing a method from the activity (in a fire-and-forget fashion) and calling Task.Delay in that method. But even in this mechanism we are still facing the same problem where the thread stops responding as soon as it hits Task.Delay.

```
public class CommandStatusCheckerActivity : BaseCodeActivity<Job>      //Last Activity in the Workflow
{   
    protected override Job Execute(CodeActivityContext context)
    {
        var job = JobContext.Get(context);
        var statusUpdater = new JobStatusUpdaterAsync();

        //Fire and Forget
        Task.Run(
            () => statusUpdater.Update(job));

       return job;
    }
}


public class JobStatusUpdaterAsync
{   
    public JobStatusUpdaterAsync()
    {
        //Initialization
    }

    public void Update(Job job)
    {
        var iteration = 1;
        do
        {
            _tableLogger.LogMessage(“Sleep Started”);
            Task.Delay(backoffDelay).Wait();
            _tableLogger.LogMessage(“Active Again”); //This Line is never executed

            //Actual Polling Logic
            iteration++;
        } while (ellapsedTime < timeout && inprogressItems.Any());
    }
}
```

I would like to call out that at the same time there are multiple operations which are happening in the worker role and all those threads are getting completed successfully. But none of the other threads have a Task.Delay in them.

Surprisingly we cannot reproduce the same situation in Local machine, it's happening only in our Cloud Service Worker Role.

Out Worker Role Size in Standard_D2.

Any guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you post more of the code?

Comment: @RubbleFord, added the code and given a few more details

Comment: It's hard to see from this amount of code, but are you dropping out and terminating. I can see Task.Run executing the action hence not blocking etc. and executing continuing. In the caller have you got something that stops the overall process from terminating? If not that would potentially explain this issue.